# Composing Translations and Reflections

Tags: functions, operator-theory

Since $f(-x)$ is a reflection of $f(x)$ in the $y$-axis and $f(x+a)$ is a shift of $f(x)$ by $-a$ units, so for the longest time I've assumed $f(-(x+a))$ is a shift of $-a$ and then reflected in the $y$-axis.

But graphing some things, I've noticed this actually gives a shift of $+a$, then reflection in $y$-axis? Rewriting $f(-(x+a))$ as $f(-x-a)$ reads reflect, then shift by $+a$ to me, which is equivalent to the former, but produces the latter.

Am I reading the order of operations wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is always confusing (to me as well), and I find myself having to write it down every time -- and even then, a mistake is easily made.

Let us we write $S$ for the reflection operation $f(x) \mapsto f(-x)$ and $T_a$ for the "translation by $a$"-operation $f(x) \mapsto f(x-a)$.

The crux here is that $S$ is *not* the same as the function $x \mapsto -x$. Similarly, $T_a$ is *not* the same as $x \mapsto x-a$.

---

Let us see what is going on. We must consider the following compositions (I suppress the composition symbol $\circ$ for readability):

$$ST_a,\  ST_{-a}, \ T_aS,\ T_{-a}S$$

So, let's take an arbitrary function $f$, and apply the definitions:

\begin{align}
T_a (f) &= x \mapsto f(x-a) \\
T_{-a}(f) &= x \mapsto f(x+a) \\
S(f) &= x \mapsto f(-x)
\end{align}

What is important to keep in mind, is that $ST_a(f) = S(T_a(f))$. So $S$ is applied to the *new function* $x \mapsto f(x-a)$, and *not* to the entire argument of $f$, that is, to $x-a$. So, in full detail, we obtain:

\begin{align}
ST_a(f) &= S(x \mapsto f(x-a)) = x \mapsto f((-x)-a) = f(-x-a)\\
ST_{-a}(f) &= S(x \mapsto f(x+a)) = x\mapsto f((-x)+a) = f(a-x)\\
T_aS(f) &= T_a(x \mapsto f(-x)) = x \mapsto f(-(x-a)) = f(a-x)\\
T_{-a}S(f) &= T_{-a}(x \mapsto f(-x)) = x \mapsto f(-(x+a)) = f(-x-a)
\end{align}

(I hope that the $x \mapsto \dots$ notation is not too confusing for you.)

In conclusion, we have that $ST_a = T_{-a}S$ and $ST_{-a} = T_aS$. Intuitively:

> "If you pull something towards you from a mirror, then looking in the mirror, you see its mirror image moving away from you."

---

**Added** (as suggested by Trevor Wilson):

What the above amounts to, is that we can write $f(-(x+a))$ as $(ST_a(f))(x)$ or as $(T_{-a}S(f))(x)$ (because, and this is important, $ST_a(f)$ and $T_{-a}S(f)$ are still *functions*, which we can evaluate at $x$). In more advanced treatises, the extraneous brackets are omitted, to yield: $$f(-(x+a)) = ST_af(x) = T_{-a}Sf(x)$$

---

**Further addition -- generalities on transformation operators:**

So far, we've been kind of vague on what a transformation operator exactly is, and dealt with examples.

Now, suppose that we have a mapping $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ (usually, but not necessarily, a bijection). E.g. $g_1(x) = -x$, or $g_2(x) = x-a$.

Then the **operator defined by $g$** (which I will denote $O(g)$) is the mapping $O(g): \Bbb R^{\Bbb R} \to \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ which takes a function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ to: $$O(g)f: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R, x \mapsto f(g(x))$$

We sometimes refer to $O(g)$ as *precomposition by $g$*: it maps $f$ to $f \circ g$: "$g$ before $f$".

Recalling the examples $g_1$ and $g_2$, we see $S = O(g_1)$ and $T_a = O(g_2)$.

Now, let us see what happens if we look at $O(gh)$ (again, I suppress $\circ$ for readability) for some suitable functions $g,h$:

$$O(gh)f = fgh = O(h)(fg) = O(h)O(g)f$$

Ah-hah! $O$ *reverses* the order of composition.

Now let us return to our concrete setting. For conceptual clarity, let us write $t_a$ for the mapping $x \mapsto x-a$ (so that $T_a = O(t_a)$), $s$ for $x \mapsto -x$ and $m_b$ for $x \mapsto bx$.

If we would want to write $f(bx+a)$ using translation and scaling, we'd observe that:

$$bx+a = t_{-a}(bx) = t_{-a}m_b(x)$$

Switching to the $O$ notation, we get:

$$f(bx+a) = O(t_{-a}m_b)f(x) = O(m_b)O(t_{-a})f(x) = M_bT_{-a}f(x)$$

In conclusion, the fact that $O$, *precomposition*, is composition-reversing gives rise to the counterintuitive order of operations. I hope this provides you with a better understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I think it would clarify your answer if you wrote down how to express $f(-(x+a))$ in terms of $S$, $T_{\pm a}$, $f$, and $x$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Thanks for the advice, done.

Comment: The confusing part to me is that the - sign in the (x-a) usually means translate to the right, whereas when you have a reflection AFTER the translation, the - sign represents translation to the right. This can get even more confusing when you have a horizontal stretch and have to factor things out to see the scale of the translation.

Overall, how would one read f(-(x-a)) starting with the translation i.e. in order of operators

Comment: @user103312 Ok, so we want to do precisely one translation, say by $b$ (we anticipate that $b = \pm a$, but let's keep it abstract). So let us define $g = T_bf$, that is, $g(x) = f(x-b)$. Any further transformation will act on $g$. But it is as if $g$ "does not know about $b$". A transformation on $g$ cannot affect $b$ in any way; it can only affect the $x$ in $f(x-b)$. Back to our situation. Let's think of our target as $g(A(x)) = f(A(x)-b)$, with $A(x)$ a suitable function of $x$ that will be determined by the operations we will perform after $T_b$. (continued)

Comment: Our assumption was that we'd do only one translation. So, $A(x)$ won't introduce new constant terms (basically, we assume $A(0)=0$). Thus, we need $f(-(x-a)) = f(A(x)-b)$ for all $x$; that is, $-(x-a) = A(x)-b$. So, by our assumption, $-(0-a) = 0-b$, i.e. $b = -a$. Then, we can look at $-(x-a)=A(x)-b$ again, and conclude that $A(x) = -x$. Therefore, $f(-(x-a))$ is the same as $ST_{-a}f(x)$. Does that clarify things for you?

Comment: Clarifies somewhat. Lets try to build a general method to describe these operations:

f(x+a): Translate f(x) by -a
f(-(x+a)): Translate f(x) by +a and reflect in y-axis
So in general:
f(b(x+a)): if b>0 Translate by -a and scale horizontally by b, else translate by +a, reflect in y axis and scale by -b (or assume scaling by b takes care of reflection since b<0)

Comment: @user103312 Well, not quite. You see (using $M_b$ for scaling by $b$), we can always describe $f(b(x+a))$ as $T_{-a}M_bf(x)$: $f(x)\to f(bx)\to f(b(x+a))$. But if we want it with $M_b$ in front, we need to watch out: $M_bT_{-a}f(x)$ gets built up as $f(x) \to f(x+a)\to f(bx+a)$. So we actually see that $M_bT_{-ab} f(x)$ equals $T_{-a}M_bf(x)$. Your proposed solution for $b <0$ has a similar defect: $M_{-b}ST_af(x)$ gives rise to $f(x)\to f(x-a)\to f(-x-a)\to f(-bx-a)$. Really, it requires practice, and I recommend that when you come up with something, you test it explicitly on some paper.

Comment: OK so that's exactly my problem. Mb T−a f(x) gets built up as f(x)→f(x+a)→f(bx+a) as you said. The first thing is using operators and you read those right to left (shift then scale) for order, while the f(bx+a) is read scale then shift by algerbraic order of operations which is the opposite. See my problem?

Comment: @user103312 I've added a general explanation that will probably make some things clear for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misusing the following rule:

> (1) The graph of $f(-x)$ as a function of $x$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $f(x)$ as a function of $x$ in the vertical axis.

You appear to be using something like the following statement, which is not vaild.

> (2) The graph of $f(-(x+a))$ as a function of $x$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $f(x+a)$ as a function of $x$ in the vertical axis.

The problem is confusing because statement (2) happens to be "almost" correct in the sense that it only differs from the correct statement by a translation.
So to get a sense of why we should not expect statements along the lines of (2) to be valid in general, let's replace the function $x \mapsto x+a$ in (2) by a totally different function, say $x \mapsto x^2$.  Then the same reasoning that gave us (2) would give us

> (3) The graph of $f(-x^2)$ as a function of $x$ is obtained by reflecting the graph of $f(x^2)$ as a function of $x$ in the vertical axis.

But statement (3) is clearly false: The graph of $f(-x^2)$ as a function of $x$ depends only on the values of $f$ on arguments $\le 0$ and may be wildly different from the graph of $f(x^2)$ as a function of $x$, which depends only on the values of $f$ on arguments $\ge 0$.